# SOAP Client Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, soap

I am making a SOAP request to FedEX using PHP. I am trying to upload a file. **If the file size is less than approx 48KB the upload is fine**. Anything greater than that and the upload fails, $exception->faultstring = "Request Entity Too Large", Code = "HTTP String". FedEX have done a test and have said that they can upload my test file that fails fine and that the problem is with my client and not their server. They say the endpoint accepts several MB, yet I am uploading about 60KB.

I have tried hosting my php pages on IIS (Windows Server 2016) and also on a cPanel (apache?) webserver and I get the same error with both web servers. I am using the FedEX example code to send the data.

This is where I set the content, it's quite simple:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1));

foreach ( $parameters->documents as $doc ) { 

    $request['Documents'][$docIndex]['LineNumber'] = $doc->LineNumber;
    $request['Documents'][$docIndex]['DocumentType'] = $doc->DocumentType;
    $request['Documents'][$docIndex]['FileName'] = $doc->FileName;
    $request['Documents'][$docIndex]['DocumentContent'] = base64_decode($doc->Content);

    $request['Documents'][$docIndex]['DocumentUsageType'] = $doc->DocumentUsageType;
    
    $docIndex++;
}
try {
    $newLocation = $client->__setLocation( setFedEXEndpoint($parameters->production) );
    $response = $client ->uploadDocuments($request);
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
   echo '<h2>Fault</h2>' . "<br>\n";                        
   echo "<b>Code:</b>{$exception->faultcode}<br>\n";
   echo "<b>String:</b>{$exception->faultstring}<br>\n";
}
```

and a portion of the WSDL

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/uploaddocument/v19" xmlns:s1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="http://fedex.com/ws/uploaddocument/v19" name="UploadDocumentServiceDefinitions">
  <types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://fedex.com/ws/uploaddocument/v19">
      <xs:element name="UploadDocumentsReply" type="ns:UploadDocumentsReply"/>
      <xs:element name="UploadDocumentsRequest" type="ns:UploadDocumentsRequest"/>
      <xs:element name="UploadDocumentsWithShipmentDataReply" type="ns:UploadDocumentsWithShipmentDataReply"/>
      <xs:element name="UploadDocumentsWithShipmentDataRequest" type="ns:UploadDocumentsWithShipmentDataRequest"/>
      <xs:element name="UploadImagesReply" type="ns:UploadImagesReply"/>
      <xs:element name="UploadImagesRequest" type="ns:UploadImagesRequest"/>
```

My web server will receive the file fine as a POST parameter to my php page. The SOAP request on that PHP page is what is failing. Any idea what I should change on the client to allow more content to go out in the SOAP request?

This is the response I get:

**Fault
Code:HTTP
String:Request Entity Too Large**

Server PHP version: PHP Version 7.4.9

Comment: You should share the SOAP code.

Comment: "Failing" with which error?

Comment: I have added more SOAP code and more details, if I'm missing something please let me know. I left out half of the $request which is just login information and other such things.

Comment: @HonkderHase the error is $exception->faultcode = HTTP String, $exception->faultstring = Request Entity Too Large

Comment: If I read their documentation correct -> `The maximum size of an image
can only be 700 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall.`. Maybe that is the issue at hand.

Comment: @GuidoFaecke FedEX have confirmed that my test document is fine. They can upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was the endpoint.
I was uploading to:

> 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/'

I needed to upload to:

> 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/uploaddocument'

It seems the wrong endpoint will still accept and process the request, but the correct endpoint accepts larger files.